# Finding lines of similar attribute with respect to nodes connected to its both Ends

Tags: arcgis-desktop, postgis, postgresql

I have line networks with node generated for Start and End Point . how to check if a line has correct attribute with respect to point created at its End. for instance `FuID_Line = ABC_BDQ` and Start Point having `FuID_Po =ABC` and End point having `FuID = BDQ`.

Update:

I think I am not clear enough previously in my question. actually I dont want to generate points. I have lines and with end points(Start/End) already given what I want to check is if line has
`FuID = 560_960` attribute. it should have start point value `pID=560` and End point value `pID=960`.

I want to join attributes to line feature something similar to this one

```
+--------+---------+-----+-------+---------+
| obj_id |  Fuid   | pid | pid_1 | remark  |
+--------+---------+-----+-------+---------+
|      1 | 560_960 | 560 |   960 | match   |
|      2 | 960_560 | 960 |   560 | match   |
|      3 | 261_690 | 260 |   690 | unmatch |
|      4 | 420_921 | 420 |   926 | unmatch |
+--------+---------+-----+-------+---------+
```

[image]

Note:Lines are sometimes overlapped to each other.

Answer (score 1):

Use spatial join between your points and your lines, with the JOIN_ONE_TO_ONE option. You can get attributes from both points using the "first" and "last" merge rules.

[image]

If the order is important, generate each end point type (START /END) separately using feature vertices to points then join.

Comment: what do you mean `You can get attributes from both points using the "first" and "last" merge rules`. where is this option in `spatial join`.

Comment: please read updates on this question above.